# Template Template C++ Function

Tags: c++, templates, std

How do I write a template function that operates on a arbitrary container of a arbitrary type? For example how do I *generalize* this dummy function

```
template <typename Element>
void print_size(const std::vector<Element> & a)
{
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

to

```
template <template<typename> class Container, typename Element>
void print_size(const Container<Element> & a)
{
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

Here is a typical usage

```
std::vector<std::string> f;
print_size(f)
```

This give error

```
tests/t_distances.cpp:110:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘print(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’. I'm guessing I must tell the compiler something more specific about what types that are allowed.
```

What is this *variant of template-use* called and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 15):

Is there a specific reason for you to use a template template? Why not just like this?

```
template <typename Container>
void print_size(Container const& a)
{
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

In general, template templates aren’t worth the trouble. In your particular case, there certainly is no use for them, and if you really need to access the member type, I suggest you bow to common practice and use a metafunction (`typename Container::value_type` in this case).

Comment: What if you need to get the "contained" type ? Like if you want to create a function who gives you a std::map from two std::vector (one for the keys, the other for the values). But you could use something else than std::vector like a custom class with begin() and end() iterators.

Comment: @ibizaman That’s what typendefs are for. Just use `typename Container::value_type` (note the prefixed `typename`, it’s important; there are other questions explaining why).

Comment: is this value_type standard ? Well, I know it's in the stl for std::vector and so but is it the acknowledged way of doing it for custom classes ?

Comment: @ibizaman Yes. Custom containers should do the same as native containers. If they don’t (I know some libraries where that’s the case), it’s *their* job to provide fitting adapters.

Comment: This is exactly what concepts (in c++ terminology) is about, right ?

Answer (score 6):

I know that the question was asked long time ago , but i had same problem , and the solution is that you need to write

```
template <template <typename,typename> class Container, typename element, typename Allocator>
void print_size(Container<element, Allocator> & a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << std::endl;
}
```

because the vector has two template parameters

Answer (score 3):

Why ever use something like

```
template <template<typename> class Container, typename Element>
void print_size(const Container<Element> & a)
{
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

? Use it in simpler way:

```
template<typename Container>
void print_size(const Container & a)
{
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

When calling `print_size(f)`, you will call `print_size` with `Container` being `vector<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `vector` template takes two type arguments, and your template accepts only template arguments that accept a single argument. The simplest solution is lifting a bit of the type safety and just using `Container` as a type:

```
template <typename Container>
void print_size( Container const & c ) {
   std::cout << c.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Possibly adding static checks (whatever the type `Container` is, it must have a `value_type` nested type that is `Element`...) The alternative would be to make the template template argument match the templates that are to be passed (including allocator for sequences, allocator and order predicate for associative containers)...

Answer (score 0):

For these types of *generic* algorithms, I always prefer iterators, i.e.

```
template <typename IteratorType>
void print_size(IteratorType begin, IteratorType end) {
   std::cout << std::distance(begin, end) << std::endl;
}
```

To call:

```
std::vector<std::string> f;
print_size(f.begin(), f.end());
```

Comment: Why would you prefer this, particularly seeing that `distance` can have worse algorithmic complexity than the `size` member function?

Comment: @UncleBens - yes - that's true for non random-access iterators, in this case - there should be no difference. Anyway, this example is trivial, what I mean is that (all)most standard library algorithms work with iterators, so why not do your algorithms in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

From **C++20**, something like below is possible. Just declare print function with `auto` parameter.

```
void print_size(auto container)
{
    std::cout << container.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector vecOfInts = { 2,4,6,8 };
    std::map<int, int> mapOfInts = { {2,4},{6,8},{10,12} };

    print_size(vecOfInts);
    print_size(mapOfInts);
}
```