# Template function, can't figure out

Tags: c++, templates

Even after referring to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ and [Template Template C++ Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555391/template-template-c-function), I still don't understand clearly.

If I have a given function, say

in `week.cpp`

```
void week::writeDate (const Vector<long>& L)
```

in `week.h`

```
void writeDate (const Vector<long>& L)
```

Do I simply write `Template <week L>` before the function names on both cpp and h?
Or would it entail more than that?

Or does the whole "week" class have to be a template itself?

Comment: What do you want to be a template parameter? The `long`? Nothing in your current code needs to be made into a template.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you want your function to accept only `const std::vector<long>&` then you don't have to do anything.

Comment: I have been instructed to make function templates, getting compile errors

Comment: @SndLt But what about the function should vary? Your function takes a `const std::vector<long>&`. That's a fixed type. There's nothing to vary.

Comment: Parameter as in, the vector I am passing in?

Comment: @SndLt What are you hoping to achieve by making it a function template?

Comment: I want other classes to be able to easily access "week"'s functions

Comment: @SndLt if they are public functions, they already can.  `template` doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: @SndLt What do you mean by "easily access"? What is not easy about accessing that function?

Comment: I want this to be a generic that can be used in other types

Comment: @SndLt You seem to misunderstand templates. What exactly do you want to be generic about `week`? By the way, the StackOverflow question you linked to is about template template parameters, which is way too advanced for you at the moment.

Comment: @SndLt it sounds like you have some misunderstanding about what `template` does.  Can you edit your question so it's clear what your code is currently unable to do?

Comment: @SndLt There's a difference between using templates like vector (which is easy) and writing your own (which is harder). I think you're getting them mixed up.

Comment: I think what he means is that he wants to use `writeDate` not just for `Vector<long>` but for other types too e.g. `Vector<int>` . is that correct @SndLt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In week.h

```
template <class T>
void writeDate (const Vector<T>& L)
{
   // code for function
}
```

In week.cpp

```
// nothing at all
```

This is called a member function template (or template member function).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `writeDate` for a vector of any type. Then you have to make it a template function. I can't see the whole code so I don't know if you use the type of the vector in your week class somewhere else but if you need it just for `writeDate` then

```
class week {
    // Other stuff

    template< typename T>
    void writeDate (const Vector<T>& L){
         // code goes here.
        }
// Other stuff

}
```

if your week class depends on the type of the vector somehow then

```
template < typename T>
class week {
// Other stuff

    void writeDate (const Vector<T>& L) {
     // code goes here.
    }

// Other stuff

}
```