# STL container as template parameter in function, error in call

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++03

Cant understand what is wrogn with code, second function definition or call of this function in main?
I think, but not sure, problem in call, cause without calling code compiles well. Compiler gcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void show_element(T ob)
{
    cout << ob << " ";
}

template<template<class> class S, class T>
void show_sequence(S<T> sequence)
{
    for_each(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), show_element<T>);    
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v(20, 0);

    //here the problem
    show_sequence<std::vector<int>, int>(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: algorithms.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
algorithms.cpp:29:40: error: no matching function for call to 'show_sequence(std::vector<int>&)'
algorithms.cpp:29:40: note: candidate is:
algorithms.cpp:18:6: note: template<template<class> class S, class T> void show_sequence(S<T>)

Comment: Add the error message to the question.

Comment: I suggest you take a hint from the algorithm functions (like e.g. [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) that you use) and have the function takes iterators instead. Then you can use the function not only with the standard containers but also with arrays or pointers.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but its not really what I want here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` isn't a template of one parameter, it takes an allocator type as well. You can use it as `vector<T>` simply because the second parameter has a default (`std::allocator<T>`).

As it's written, your template function cannot accept any standard container, since off the top of my head, none take just a single type parameter.

An approach that would work, and not require you to know how many template parameters a container requires, is to accept a container **type** (not template), and glean the value type from the container type.

```
template<class Seq>
void show_sequence(Seq const& sequence)
{
    typedef typename Seq::value_type T;
    for_each(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), show_element<T>);    
}
```

All standard containers have a `value_type` member, so this will work with any of them. Furthermore, it will work with any container that takes its cue from the standard library.

Comment: What do you mean when you write "std::vector isn't a template of one parameter", that I must to write template<class, class> for any stl containers in template declaration?

Comment: I know about Allocator, but how this info can help me in current situation?

Comment: @Anton - By the mere fact that if you accept a template, you must specify exactly what parameters it takes, and whatever template is passed must match those exactly. Accepting a template (and not a container type) will always limit what containers you can accept. For instance, what if you wanted to show a `std::map`? That container template has 4 parameters. 3 of those aren't of interest to you, but your solution must take them into account. Using `value_type` will makes those considerations go away.

Comment: User scinart show me what I want, but your variant is more better) Thank you for your explanation, very helpful and useful

Comment: You could use as well variadic templates to help you to have other templates parameter ;)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier - Which won't work for `std::array`. There's a reason the standard library opted to have the containers expose traits.

Comment: Ha yeah because array take std::size_t template parameter...
One time, I write a trait is_iterable (by checking for begin() and end() function). And instead to have a template 'template parameter', I had just a template parameter with a check (through SFINAE) if this type parameter is iterable. And it was good enough to my uses :).

Comment: 1. using T = typename Seq::value_type; doesnt work in gcc, I use instead 'typename Sequence::value_type T;'
2. Now I have error with for_each func:
algorithms.cpp:22:5: error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
algorithms.cpp:22:5: note: candidate is:
c:\users\a.iovbak\desktop\pro\portablegit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4373:5: note: template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)

Comment: @Anton - It does work if you are compiling your code as C++11 or later (the current standard). If you do not, you should have specified that in your post.

Comment: @Anton - The C++03 was added by me, because of your comment. There is no need for another answer. The edited solution above works in C++03 and any future version. The original one was geared toward C++11 only because it's not unreasonable to assume people will be using mostly that now.

Comment: No comment. THNX

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `std::vector` is a template but `std::vector<int>` is a type.

When you are giving the second one to the function, you are giving one type and not a template.

So, you can rewrite your function as :

```
template<class S>
void show_sequence(S sequence)
```

Moreover, vector does not take only one template paramete but two (see StoryTeller answer)

Answer (score 2):

It is similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29493191/1889040

It is because vector is template of `<type, allocator>`

The code should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
void show_element(T ob)
{
    cout << ob << " ";
}
template<template<class,class> class S, class T, class Allocator>
void show_sequence(S<T, Allocator> sequence)
{
    for_each(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), show_element<T>);
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v(20, 0);

    //here problem solved
    show_sequence<vector, int, allocator<int> > (v);
    show_sequence(v);

    return 0;
}
```