# how to use type alias in writing template template functions

Tags: c++

I have a template class as follows.

```
template <class T>
class Point
{
    T x;
    T y;
    using value_type = T;
    Point() {}
    Point(T a, T b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};
```

I want to write a function that adds x and y values and return x+y in the type the class is defined. One way is to use a template template as follows:

```
template <typename T2, template <typename> class T1>
T2 sum(T1<T2> p)
{
    return p.x + p.y;
}
```

I was wondering is it possible to use type alias defined in the class and avoid writing a template template for the sum function and get similar results? There are similar concerns pointed out in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555391/template-template-c-function), but the use of type alias is not discussed there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template Template C++ Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555391/template-template-c-function)

Comment: @BattleTested Although the titles are similar, the question you referred to does not discuss using type alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can.

```
template <typename T>
typename T::value_type sum(T p)
{
    return p.x + p.y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to do the following:

```
template <class T>
T sum(Point<T> p) {
  return p.x + p.y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, to avoid making `sum()` accept an overly broad set of types:

```
template <typename T>
typename Point<T>::value_type sum(const Point<T>& p)
{
    return p.x + p.y;
}
```

It's `const&` in case `T` is large or expensive to copy, and `typename` is required because `value_type` is a dependent name (dependent on the type passed as `T`), so without that the code won't compile as `value_type` could be a value instead of a type.

A more generic alternative which allows for types `T` whose `operator+` do  not result in `T` would be:

```
template <typename T>
auto sum(const Point<T>& p)
{
    return p.x + p.y;
}
```

This does not strictly answer your question of how to use the type alias `value_type`, but it is probably better code, as it does not place unnecessary restrictions on `T`.